# form validation for js w/ axios

Tags: javascript, validation, axios

I'm having trouble with my code for validating that all the fields in my form are filled before submitting. I tried putting an if-statement inside my event listener but it didn't seem to work. I was wondering if anyone had an idea of how this could be achieved. I looked at W3 and other examples but they didn't seem to work. here is my code. I also don't want to do this with HTML validation as it is easy to go into the dev tools and remove the required attribute of the input element. Any help would be appreciated. I also attached the CSS for styling purposes.

```js
var form = document.querySelector("#user_form");

    let reqHeaders = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer ",
        }
    }

    let url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appMPvHoTHviahyfz/email-list"

    let reqData = {
        records: [
            {
                fields: null
            }
        ]
    }

    let formData = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: ""
    }

    function logData(id, dataObj, value) {

        dataObj[id] = value;

        console.log(value)
    }

    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        reqData.records[0].fields = formData;

        console.log(reqData);

        axios.post(url, reqData, reqHeaders).then(res => {
            document.querySelector('.success-messg').style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(function(){
                form.reset();
                document.querySelector('.success-messg').style.display = 'none';
            },2000)
        })
        .catch (err => {
            if (err.reponse){
                document.querySelector('.fail-messg').style.display = 'block';
                setTimeout(function(){
                    document.querySelector('.fail-messg').style.display = 'none';
                    form.reset();
                }, 3000)
            } else if (err.request) {
                document.querySelector('.fail-messg').style.display = 'block';
                setTimeout(function(){
                    document.querySelector('.fail-messg').style.display = 'none';
                    form.reset();
                }, 3000)
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    });
```

```css
.form-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}

#user_form{
  height: 11rem;
  width:30rem;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  bottom:0;
  top:55vh;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:4;
}

.form-wrapper input{
  border:0;
  color:black;
  background-color:#f9da06;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
  width:10.5rem;
  margin:1.2rem;
}

.form-wrapper input:focus{
  border:0;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
  outline:none;
}

.form-wrapper ::placeholder {
  color:black;
  opacity: 1;
}

#info-submit{
  background-color:black;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#f9da06;
  border:0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height:2.289rem;
  width:10.5rem;
  outline:0;
}

.success-messg {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  height:4rem;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  bottom:0;
  top:80vh;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:none;
}

.fail-messg{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  height: 2rem;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  bottom:0;
  top:80vh;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
                <form id="user_form">
                        <input type="name" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name..." name="Firstname" onChange="logData(id, formData, this.value)">
                        <input type="name" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name..." name="Lastname" onChange="logData(id, formData, this.value)">
                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email..." name="email" onChange="logData(id, formData, this.value)">
                        <input type="submit" id="info-submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
                <div class="success-messg"><p>Thank you for your submission!</p></div>
                <div class="fail-messg"><p>Sorry, we were unable to take your submission at this time.</p></div>
            </div>
            
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS snippet doesn't seem to be working, but I'll try to help the best I can with what you have given.

You could do something like making a try catch block inside the event listener function, then throw an error each specific to their own, and then each of that error gets handled with a specific task that you have in mind, by looking at your code I'm going to recommend you to take a look at this and have a go on your own.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    //Throw an error if a field in the form is an empty string
    for (const data in formData) {
      if (formData[data] === "") {
        const error = new Error();
        //Set the not valid attribute to true so that it can be handled specifically
        error.notValid = true;
        throw error;
      }
    }

    reqData.records[0].fields = formData;

    console.log(reqData);
    axios
      .post(url, reqData, reqHeaders)
      .then((res) => {
        document.querySelector(".success-messg").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function () {
          form.reset();
          document.querySelector(".success-messg").style.display = "none";
        }, 2000);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        //Throw back the axios error
        throw err;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.reponse) {
      document.querySelector(".fail-messg").style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector(".fail-messg").style.display = "none";
        form.reset();
      }, 3000);
    } else if (err.request) {
      document.querySelector(".fail-messg").style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector(".fail-messg").style.display = "none";
        form.reset();
      }, 3000);
    } else if (err.notValid) {
      console.log("Notvalid");
      //Do what you want if the form is not validated
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
});
```

This type of error handling is much easier and cleaner using the ES2017 async/await and combining it with the try catch block. In your code for example since, axios returns a Promise it can be handled with async/await.

For more information on error handling and using async/await :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

I recommend that you put a server-side validation as well, because even by using dev tools someone can still change your front-end JavaScript code.